using TRIM and RIGHT commands with XLOOKUP in VBA programming
I am trying to automate query and insertion from some spreadsheets. An I have to trim and truncate the contents of cells BEFORE running the XLOOKUP command of Excel. On spreadhseets, things work perfectly. However, with VBA I am running into object declarion and array format problems.
Is there away to nest such functions within VBA of Excel? That is XLOOKUP(RIGHT(TRIM(<Cell__Range>), 8)) without having to copy this into another helper column?
I know the next piece of code is terrible but I have been trying different approaches, but none of them worked.
Probably, I need to use 'With' or 'Çell'-based commands to avoid creating an extra column. Any suggestion?
Many thanks in advance,
 Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C500")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lookFor As Variant
        Dim rng, mcu, temp As Range
        Dim isbn As Variant

        lookFor = Target.Value 'read the selected cell value
        Set rng = Range("J2") 'Get the VIN cells range
        Set mcu = Range("M2:M50") 'Get the MCU cells range
        
        ' ********** MODIFY CELL VALUES *********
        'temp.Value = Trim(Range("J2"))
        MsgBox Trim(Range("J2"))
        'rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Right(rng, 8)
        'isbn = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(lookFor, rng, mcu, False)

        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Sheets("AAP Dashboard").Range("C4").Value = isbn
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'Dim MyVIN, OtherVIN, OtherMCU As Range
        'MyVIN = Target
        'OtherMCU.Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(MyVIN.Value, Range("J2:11"), Range("M2:M11"))
        'OtherMCU.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(MyVIN.Value, Range("J2:J5"), Range("M2:M5"))
        
       
    End If
 
End Sub


I tried to read the contents of C column by double clicking it. Then I want 'TRIM', and get the latest 8 characters'RIGHT(TRIM(), 8)' from the clicked cell. Then, 'XLOOKUP' the result versus a user-input data, and extract the contents of other columns of the d-clicked worksheet that correspond to the row of the clicked cell.

lookFor = Right(Trim(Target.Value), 8)  If you're still having problems, please update your question with the actual code you're using, along with what specific error(s) you're getting, and on which line(s).  We don't know what to make of all that commented-out code, so unless it's in use it's best to remove it.
